# Why does my website look messed up in mobile browsers despite using media queries?

Tags: css, browser, media-queries, responsive

I am using media queries to make my website responsive to different screen sizes. The thing is I get different results on my cell phone, on developer tools of chrome on my laptop and on mobile screen size emulator websites!

Shouldn't they all look the same?!

P.S: I check this website to see how my website looks on different screen sizes:
http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/multi-screen-test

But what I see there, is different from what I actually get when I browse my website on my cell phone!

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
#cards_right_column {
    width: 69.3vw;
    height: 4.3vh;
    top: -21.8vh;
    right: 56.1vw;
    font-size: 1em;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#cards_left_column  {
    position: relative;
    top: -4.75vh;
    right: 1vw;
    width: 95.5vw;
    height: 46.4vh;
}
```

Comment: Try using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head>` tag of you html.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul Thanks but I'm already using it.

Comment: [We can't tell why the code you haven't shown us](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) doesn't behave in the way you expect. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin Codes are fine. It's just that I get three different versions of my website! Like three different CSS codes!
It's just simple CSS codes and media queries for different screen sizes but I don't get same results on my phone browser and windows browser and phone screen emulator websites! So practicaly I can't style my website!

Comment: @Ata — So you think that the code which describes how the website should look has no influence on it looking different on different devices?

Comment: @Quentin I'm saying if I add a 10px padding for a div for 360px+ width screens, I should see that 10px on all 360px+ width screens no matter how I browse my website. Not that I see 8px padding on my mobile chrome and 12px padding on my windows chrome (developers tools set to 360px+ width). Right?!

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin I edited my question and added a few lines of my CSS.

Comment: A [mcve] should provide enough information to reproduce the problem.